# How do I zoom/pan without redraw using d3js on canvas

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to use d3.contour to draw multiple contours on canvas. My data is composed by 200 000 points. Here, you can see the display : 
http://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=19/27/flkz.png

When I zoom in, it's too slow because I have to draw the path again. Is it possible to zoom without redraw these contours ?

And here, this is my code with the zoom function and the draw command : context.beginPath();

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>

    function update(data) {
        var cntrs = contours.thresholds(d3.range(dataCfg.min, dataCfg.max, dataCfg.step))(data);

         context.save();
        context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        context.translate(transform.x, transform.y);
        context.scale(transform.k, transform.k);
        cntrs.forEach(c => {
            if(!c.coordinates.length) return;
            context.beginPath();
            path(c);
            context.fillStyle = colorScale(c.value);
            context.fill();
        });
        context.restore();
    }

    function getConf() {
        fetch('conf.json')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log('getConf > OK');
                width = data.latlon.nblon;
                height = data.latlon.nblat;
                canvas.attr('width', width);
                canvas.attr('height', height);
                contours = d3.contours().size([width, height]);
                projection = d3.geoIdentity().scale(canvas.property('width') / width);
                path = d3.geoPath(projection, context);
                getData('t2m');
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }

    function getData(type) {
        fetch(type + '.json')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log('getData %o > OK', type);
                update(data);
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }

    function zoomed() {
        transform = d3.event.transform;
        getData('t2m');

    }

    canvas.call(d3.zoom()
          .scaleExtent([1, 8])
          .on("zoom", zoomed));

    (function() {
        getConf();
    })();
</script>
```

With svg, I do not have the problem because I am not forced to redraw the path.

Thanks for your help !